# Graphing a difficult function

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Okay can anyone  explain the graph of function $$\lfloor|y|\rfloor = 4 -\lfloor|x|\rfloor$$ where $|\cdot|$ denotes Absolute Value Function and $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ denotes the floor function (Greatest Integer Function).

This is an interesting function as i was told by my teacher that this graph actually corresponds to an area. I could atmost plot |y|=4-|x|

Comment: The function, as you've written it, doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Let's take $x = 40$. Then, $4-\lfloor | x | \rfloor = -36$. But $|y| = -36$ doesn't make sense for any value of $y$. Do you mean $y = |4-|\lfloor x \rfloor| |$?

Comment: Yes the range is from [4,-4]. The function only exists within this range.

Comment: The set of all points $(x,y)$ satisfying $\lfloor|y|\rfloor = 4 -\lfloor|x|\rfloor$ is not the graph of a function.  [Here's a plot](http://i.imgur.com/G43Y1Yu.png) of this set of points.

Comment: @AntonioVargas, what program did you use to draw it?

Comment: Thanks Antonio. Got the concept of infinite points.

Comment: @Sigur I used Mathematica's RegionPlot command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Notice that for $-1<x<1$, we have $\lfloor|x|\rfloor$=0, so the corresponding $y$-values must satisfy $\lfloor|y|\rfloor=4$.  This means $-5<y\le-4$ or $4\le y<5$.  This portion of the graph corresponds to two rectangles.  Can you see them?

Now, see if you can continue for the domains $\{-2<x\le-1$ or $1\le x<2\}$, $\{-3<x\le -2$ or $2\le x<3\}$, and so on.

Comment: Yes Got it . Thanks :)